# Equivalent of Full-text on a datetime field within MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have been using the following code to update my datetime fields when the date contained is **2015-07-21** - This means it can include any time.

So i have used the following

```
Dateandtime like '%2015-07-21%'
```

This works fine but i have been reading that the use of fulltext can make this also faster so i wanted to know if there is a similar function for datetime.

Comment: `date(Dateandtime) = "2015-07-21"` ?

Comment: Apparently the above  kills the page performance worse then like

Comment: `Dateandtime>='2015-07-21' and Dateandtime<'2015-07-22'` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use as per below then it will use index-

```
Dateandtime like '2015-07-21%'
```

If your field is datetime or timestamp then you can use as suggested above and get benefit of index, but if you are fetching date from varchar/text type field means some thing can be before and after date then you can go with fulltext search.

But fulltext search is compatible only with myisam tables till mysql 5.5 and you can create fulltext index in innodb also from mysql 5.6 onwards.